# How to set a fixed IP address for a VirtualBox machine using NAT interface?

Tags: virtualbox, vboxmanage

I'd like to run some servers as VBoxHeadless machines. NAT networking with port mapping seems more than enough for me and using bridging is unnecessary. But how can I specify an IP address I want a particular machine to use?

I've only found VBoxManage modifyvm --natnet1 command, which I can use to specify a subnet (as 192.168.0/24 for example). But I want to specify an exact IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Just statically assign the IPs on the VMs within the NAT range. Just because the VMs are within a NAT network does not mean the VMs must be set for DHCP.